# Accessing iOS App's Shared Files without iTunes

Tags: ios, macos, itunes

Apps that set their `UIFileSharingEnabled` flag to true enable iTunes to browse their Document folder for so-called shared files.

Is there a way to browse these files without iTunes?

To clarify, how does [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) allow browsing the Apps Document folders?
Are there any APIs that do this?

Comment: Did you find a way to access files that are shared via iTunes sharing without connecting the device to system? I enabled iTunes file sharing in my project to download files, its downloaded successfully and I am able to access it using iTunes. But our customer can't use iTunes to view downloaded files. Is there any workaround available to fix this?

Comment: Nope. I found a tool called iTool but not much more

Comment: Thanks, also let me know, Is it possible to download files in common directory? I am researching on this, AFAIK its not possible because of iOS Sandbox, but I need some confirmation on this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) can do what you're asking.  See the example below browsing my GBA4iOS Documents folder.  This works with all devices (I am not jailbroken).

[image: PhoneView]

The [Document Picker API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) may help you access these files.

Comment: PhoneView, indeed, goes to show that these folders *can* be accessed without iTunes, and even allow going into nested folders - which iTunes does not allow. 
The question is whether or not there is an SDK that allows doing this programmatically.

Comment: @AdiShavit I have updated my answer to include a link to Apple's documentation for the Document Picker API.  This may be a good starting point for accessing these files.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: These docs are for accessing the files via an app on iOS, right? Is there such an API for accessing them from the desktop to which the phone is connected, i.e. like iTunes does?